# How can I use the MAX() to get the whole row of a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello I am writing this in Postgres,

I have 2 tables that I want to join.
The first one is named Contract and has let's say 3 fields: ID, Category and DateOfSigning
and the second one is named ContractCategory and has 3 fields : ID and ContractCategory and Cost

The Category of Contract is a foreign key to the ContractCategory in the respective table and the
ContractCategory's ID is a foreign key to the Contract ID.

What I am looking to do is to get the Category with the Maximum Cost for the Company.
So in order to do this, I get the sum of each Category in the Contract Table with the following command:

```
select "Category", Count("Category") from "Contract" group by "Category"
```

which returns the categories and their sum in the table.

After, I join this with the ContractCategory table to get the total Profit for each category on their IDs with the following command:

```
select "Category","count"*"Cost" as "MaxProfit" from ("ContractCategory" inner join(
select "Category", Count("Category") from "Contract" group by "Category") as D on ("ContractCategory" = "Category")))
```

This returns each contract and the total Profit each one gives.

Then, I want to select the whole row where the Profit is Maximum. What I do is this command which returns 1 row:  Category, TotalProfit.

```
select "Category","Profit" from(
select Max("TotalProfit") as "Profit" from(
select "Category","count"*"Cost" as "TotalProfit" from ("ContractCategory" inner join(
select "Category", Count("Category") from "Contract" group by "Category") as D on ("ContractCategory" = "Category"))) AS B) as F
inner join(
select "Category","count"*"Cost" as "MaxProfit" from ("ContractCategory" inner join(
select "Category", Count("Category") from "Contract" group by "Category") as D on ("ContractCategory" = "Category"))) AS H
on ("Profit" = "MaxProfit");
```

I am sure there is a way from the 2nd command to get the whole row but I can't find a way to do it other than the 3rd command which is probably too complex. Is there a way to return the Max value AND the Category this value belongs to?

Thank you.

Comment: A simple statement of what you are trying to do would be very helpful.

Comment: 1) Count gives the number (of contracts) , to get the sum use SUM 2) You shoulld print example date & your sql  here  http://sqlfiddle.com , it'll be easier to understand / help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use `max()`.  If you want one row returned, you would use `order by` and `limit`/`fetch first`.

I find your question really hard to follow -- no sample data, no desired results, no simple explanation of what you want to do.  But if you wanted the category with the maximum profit, it would look something like this:

```
select cc.Category, sum(cost)
from contract c join
     contractcategory cc
     on c.ContractCategory = cc.Category
group by cc.Category
order by sum(cost) desc
limit 1;
```